# Macro copies cell values from some cells but not others

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to make a macro which copies some values from some cells to others. I have some code which gets the next line in the table, and then it copies the cell values and pastes them into the table. This works for only half of the cells I wish to copy however. It copy and pastes the values from cells B4 and B5 but not F5 and F7 (see below)

```
Sub YesTrade()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentDate As String

    currentDate = Date
    lastRow = Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Date

    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B4").Copy Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2)
    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B5").Copy Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3)
    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F5").Copy Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 4)
    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F7").Copy Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, so it must be what's in the cells. Are values in F5 and F7 calculated or how do they differ from B4 and B5?

Comment: if all you want are the values from one place to another, suggest avoiding the use of Copy/Paste and do it like this: `targetRange.value = sourceRange.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using simple `.Value` property of `Range` object?

```
Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B4").Value
Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B5").Value
Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F5").Value
Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F7").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using PasteSpecial or Destination. Here's one example with PasteSpecial which copy and pastes only values:

```
   'Copy values
   Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F5").Copy
   'Paste Values with PasteSpecial
   Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Example with Destination:

```
   'Copy values
   Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F5").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 4)
```

Hopefully this helps with your problem. If it doesn't, please provide more information about values in your cells.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is you're copying/pasting some formulas that would yield zero in destination sheet

you might then follow Michał Turczyn's suggestion (use `Value` property) and shorten your code with the use of `With ...End With` syntax

```
Sub YesTrade()
    Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Date
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Array(.Range("B4"), .Range("B5"), .Range("F5"), .Range("F7"))
    End With
End Sub
```

or, in a (possibly) more readable way:

```
Sub YesTrade()
    Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Date
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Array(.Range("B4"), _
                                                                                                  .Range("B5"), _
                                                                                                  .Range("F5"), _
                                                                                                  .Range("F7"))
    End With
End Sub
```